# How can I batch process HTML files to prepare them for printing?

Tags: batch, html

I have a collection of one thousand HTML files I need to clean up for printing. I need to delete all the tags inside the `<body></body>` area except for one, `<div.pg>`. The excess are navigation links which make the printouts messy and use up paper. The contents of the tags are not the same, so I can't find and replace the code excerpt, but the tags are the same insofar as there are three `<table>` tags to be deleted, each with specific class. Is there any batch processing technique or software to do this job? I'm using Windows

Comment: Write a python script for this.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows XP

Comment: Are these files you've created or just general pages on the internet?

Comment: Write a Perl script for this.

Answer (score 9):

> **one thousand HTML files … make them clean to be printed.**

An easy solution for suppressing sections *when printing* is to use a CSS stylesheet

Add something like this to the `head` element

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
   type="text/css"
   media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Note the `media="print"` - this stylesheet only applies when printing, not when viewing.

If your HTML is all formatted in a similar way, you might do this for thousands of html files in a single command with a simplistic pattern matching edit

```
perl -i -ne "print; print '<link … />' if /<head>/" dir1/*.html dir2/*.html
```

In print.css, set display:none for elements (e.g. whole divs) you don't want printed. For example

```
#menu { display: none; }
```

See [A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)

---

Update: If your thousand html files are already using a common CSS stylesheet file, the solution is even easier, no need to change or add anything in the html files, just add a section to the existing stylesheet to handle printing. For example:

```
@media screen
  {
  #menu {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@media print
  {
  #menu {display:none;}
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, the only way to solve this is with any scripting language or tool (like sed.exe or awk.exe) supporting real regular expressions OR with a XML library such as a Beanshell script running XMLUNIT .

Comment: +1 for solving the real problem, not giving them what they think is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use Notepad++. You're able to do a find/replace text across multiple files.